# How to execute a curl_exec every 10 seconds and collect the results when finished

Tags: php, curl

Hello is the PHP: curl_multi_select function suitable to execute 1 curl_exec every 10 seconds ? I wanna to execute a culr_exec every 10 seconds and collect the results when finished. I cannot figure out how to start.

Comment: should being possible. hard to explain without giving you the full answer. do you know how the `select()` system call works?

Comment: I know that system a little bit. I tryed to change the timeout but it hadn't effect because as soon as the resource will free up a new curl_exec will be executed and this may happen even in less than 10 seconds. Putting a Sleep(10) in the loop even didn't help, somehow I got always 0 response from the curl_exec, don't know why.

Comment: It would be possible in PHP but it would be a hack. If you have the choice then use a language that supports threads like python or the pthread php extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaning towards thinking [curl_multi_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) is not what you want to use here. From the docs:

> int curl_multi_select ( resource $mh [, float $timeout = 1.0 ] )
>
> Blocks until there is activity on any of the curl_multi connections.
>
> **mh** - A cURL multi handle returned by curl_multi_init().
>
> **timeout** - Time, in seconds, to wait for a response.

[curl_multi_init()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) is designed for "the processing of multiple cURL handles in parallel", which is not what you are looking for.

If you need process a curl_exec() every 10 seconds you have a few options:

- Use a scheduling tool to execute your script every 10s and store the data. (cron maybe)
- Write a wrapper script in bash or python you run manually that kicks off a php script every 10s.

You could do the latter in PHP, but you'll have to increase your max execution time as you'll hit that relatively quickly.

Comment: curl_multi_select is the way to go if it is possible that a certain request takes more than 10 seconds. this would require to have multiple requests opened in parallel. of course this function is just a part of the solution. I expect that the timeout is zero if `NULL` is passed. At least the `select()` function works this way

Comment: how can I safely schedule requests in PHP, I mean yes some requests may require more than 10 seconds and others less. So asking to complete the answer.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro I'm not going to write it for you from scratch. I've certainly given you enough to get started and a few things to try. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic